# PHP loop to retrieve each instance of a specific piece of data from within decoded JSON

Tags: php, json, loops, foreach

I'm trying to write a loop that will list all the `uid` in the JSON data. The `uid` spans two categories (shirts and pants). Below is what I have so far. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Current Code and JSON**

```
$url = 'http://foothillertech.com/student/webdesign/2018/2018benrud2/projects/retail/data2.json';
$jsonData = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
```

I can get each `uid` manually with this - `$data['shirts'][0]['uid']`, but I'm looking for a way to loop through the data to return all uid's from both the shirts and pants category.

Thank you!

**This is the code that solved my problem.**

Thank you @Don't Panic for your help!

```
foreach ($data as $item_type => $items) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $uids[] = $item['uid'];
        echo $uids[$i]."<br>";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `foreach` with a nested `foreach`? Or a `foreach` and `array_column`? Other options available.

Comment: may be `array_map_assoc` or `array_walk`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can merge the second level arrays (shirts and pants keys) and take the uid column from the result of that.

```
$uids = array_column(array_merge(...array_values($data)), 'uid');
```

Details of this expression from inside out (PREVIOUS indicates result of previous step):

- `array_values($data)` converts the string keys of the outer array ('shirts', 'pants') to numeric
- `array_merge(... PREVIOUS )` merges the two inner arrays, passing them to `array_merge` using [argument unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list). (The previous `array_values` step is needed because argument unpacking won't work on arrays with string keys.)
- `array_column( PREVIOUS , 'uid')` takes all the 'uid' values from the merged array produced by the previous steps

---

This is sort of a fancy way of doing something fairly simple, though. The code will be more clear if you just use a nested loop.

```
foreach ($data as $item_type => $items) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $uids[] = $item['uid'];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. It is not even taking into consideration the 'shirts' key in the main `$data `array. This solution is taking anything at the second level array that has a uid. So if there are some keys called 'pants' or 'hats', then it will go through all of them.

Comment: Yes, I believe that's the goal. OP states: _"I'm looking for a way to loop through the data to return all uid's from both the shirts and pants category."_

Comment: Ok. I take my comment back.

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks for your help! I'm trying to better understand your 1st solution because I believe it is a 'higher level' solution and I'm sure I'll need to use it in the future. If possible, can you add a little more detail to that explanation? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As @jon-stirling mentioned it, you can use `array_column()` to extract values from a sign column of an array. It does many others things that are beyond the scope of your question. Check it out at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Specifically for your example, the following code should give you all the `uid` extracted from `$data['shirts']`.

```php
$url = 'http://foothillertech.com/student/webdesign/2018/2018benrud2/projects/retail/data2.json';
$jsonData = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
$shirtsUids = array_column($data['shirts'], 'uid');
$pantsUids = array_column($data['pants'], 'uid');

// Then you can use $shirtsUids and $pantsUids as you see fit.
```

Make sure that the $data array has a key called shirt or else you will have an error or warning thrown.

To avoid causing an error, I using use the Null coalescing operator (`??`) to make uncertain values default to an acceptable one. So I will use `$data['shirts'] ?? []`. But again, make sure that $data['shirts'] is an array.

```php
$url = 'http://foothillertech.com/student/webdesign/2018/2018benrud2/projects/retail/data2.json';
$jsonData = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
$shirtsUids = array_column($data['shirts'] ?? [], 'uid');
$pantsUids = array_column($data['pants'] ?? [], 'uid');

// Then you can use $shirtsUids and $pantsUids as you see fit.
```